# How does Reddit display anchor tags as images?

Tags: html, image, anchor

Example here: http://www.reddit.com/r/fffffffuuuuuuuuuuuu/comments/fn9e7/the_best_thing_about_walking_to_school/c1h7af4

I tried to peek into the DOM via Firebug but I couldn't find a reference to the images. I only found that the `href` attribute of the anchor tags decides what image will be displayed. This is something new to me. How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a CSS `background-image` in the `:after` pseudo-selector.

Comment: On the <a/> tag? Firebug doesn't show any background-image property applied on the element.

Comment: Firebug doesn't show `:after`.  http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=537 Chrome does.

Answer (score 1):

Like slaks says, it's a background image. Like so:

```
<a href="link.html" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-image:url('image.jpg');"></a>
```

Comment: I realize that's not exactly how they do it, but that